# Prove that $W_n$ is 4-critical if $n$ is odd, $n \geq 3$.

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory

Let $W_n$ be a graph from $C_n$ with an added vertex, adjacent to every $n$ vertices from $C_n$.

Prove that $W_n$ is 4-critical if $n$ is odd, $n \geq 3$.

Can anyone help me formulate the complete formal proof?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose that $n\ge 3$ is odd.

- First show that $\chi(W_n)=4$; use the fact that $\chi(C_n)=3$ if $n$ is odd.

Then let $G$ be a proper subgraph of $W_n$; you want to show that $\chi(G)\le 3$. Consider two cases:

- $G$ is a subgraph of $C_n$, and
- $G$ contains the hub vertex of $W_n$.

The first case is pretty straightforward: either $G=C_n$, or the components of $G$ are paths. The second cases isn’t much harder: you should need at most two colors for the remaining non-hub vertices.

Comment: It it's not ask too much, could you please fill the gaps? I'm terrible on mathematical proofs, although I know the subject and understand what you're showing.

Comment: @Marconian I think you should try to fill in the gaps yourself!

Comment: @Marconian: It really is very straightforward, and I’d much rather that you take a stab at it. Start by trying to explain why $\chi(C_n)=3$ if $n$ is odd, and why the chromatic number of any proper subgraph of $C_n$ is $2$-colorable.